Alternative proof Box-counting dimension Cantor set
From the Book of Falconer (Fractal Geometry: Mathematical Foundations and Applications, 2nd ed.), we have the following proposition:
Proposition 3.2
Let $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \underline{\operatorname{dim}}_{\mathrm{B}} F=n-\varlimsup_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\log \mathcal{L}^n\left(F_\delta\right)}{\log \delta} \\
& \overline{\operatorname{dim}}_{\mathrm{B}} F=n-\varlimsup_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\log \mathcal{L}^n\left(F_\delta\right)}{\log \delta}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $F_\delta$ is the $\delta$-neighbourhood of $F$.
$F_\delta=\{x:|x-y| \leq \delta \text { for some } y \text { in } F\} $
Exercise 3.7 asks the following:
Let $F$ be the middle third Cantor set. For $0<\delta<1$, find the length of the $\delta$ neighbourhood $F_\delta$ of $F$, and hence find the box dimension of $F$ using Proposition 3.2.
The provided solution is the following:
The middle third Cantor set has $2^k$ gaps of length $3^{-k-1}$ for $k=0,1,2, \ldots$ If $\frac{1}{2} 3^{-k}<\delta \leq \frac{1}{2} 3^{-k-1}$ the $\delta$-neighbourhood fills the gaps of lengths $3^{-k}$ or less, and has two parts of length $\delta$ in the gaps of length $3^{-k-1}$ or more. Summing these lengths over all gaps, and noting that the parts of $F_\delta$ at each end of $F$ have length $\delta$, gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\left(F_\delta\right) & =\sum_{i=k}^{\infty} 2^{i-1} 3^{-i}+2 \delta \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} 2^{i-1}+2 \delta \\
& =\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-1}+2^k \delta
\end{aligned}
$$
on summing the geometric series. Hence
$$
2^k \delta \leq \mathcal{L}\left(F_\delta\right) \leq 2^k \delta+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-1} \leq 4 \times 2^k \delta
$$
or
$$
c_1 \delta^{1-\log 2 / \log 3} \delta \leq \mathcal{L}\left(F_\delta\right) \leq c_2 \delta^{1-\log 2 / \log 3} .
$$
Hence Proposition 3.2 gives that $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathrm{B}} F=\log 2 / \log 3$.
I am having troubles to understand this exercise. I have understood already the proof of the proposition and how to compute the box-counting dimension of $F$ without this result, but in this particular case I am stuck on how to do this exercise. Can please somebody provide me more details on how to solve this exercise? Also the start with the inequality $\frac{1}{2} 3^{-k}<\delta \leq \frac{1}{2} 3^{-k-1}$ seems to me not make sense. Thank you!

The measure (or length) of $F_\delta$, thought of as a function of $\delta$, is a step function.  It jumps at values of $\delta$ of the form $3^{-k}/2$, and is constant on the intervals between the jumps.  Do you see why that is?  (I would suggest that you start by drawing some pictures).  Is that your only question about the given solution?
